# Getting position & rotation in parent space

Tags: rotation, maxscript

I have few bones.

`Bone001`:

[image]

`Bone002`:

[image]

The are aligned in the same direction. `Bone001` has an rotation (in both World and Parent space). `Bone002` has the same rotation as `Bone001` **in World space** and it's rotation in Parent space (`Boone001`) is `0`.

I want to get the position and rotation of `Bone002` in Parent space (which should be `0`).

I have tried (according to [official documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_6C7219CF_B9B7_4B18_A846_5522A9D970F3_htm)):

```
--each and every returns the same World space pos (as $Bone002.transform.pos)
(in coordsys parent $Bone002.transform.pos)
(in coordsys local $Bone002.transform.pos)
(in coordsys $Bone001 $Bone002.transform.pos)
$Bone002.transform.pos *= inverse $Bone002.transform
```

But each and every of them returns the `Bone002` World space position (and not the Parent space one). Same for rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with the last one, to get transformation in another object's space, multiply by the inverse of that object's transform. Here, that would be:

```
obj.transform.pos * inverse obj.parent.transform
```